# Do I have to pay city "fees and fines" if I buy a foreclosed property?

Tags: real-estate, foreclosure

I am looking at a foreclosed property in NYC that has $320,000 in charges from a 2017 city tax bill. In 2016 there was a house there and then afterwards there wasn't so I guess the city demolished the house. My question is if the city has demolished the house, charged the property owner for it via tax, and I buy the property land-only at auction does that get discharged or do I have to pay for it? The property requires a "HOLD HARMLESS" agreement and a warning that the tax bill has exceeded $400k.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing about NYC is they are very good at collecting on tax.

Those costs should be considered in the business equation of purchasing this property.  One of the risks of buying auctioned distressed properties is "cleaning up the title" or "title work", basically finding and paying all the liens that have been attached to the property.

Real estate transactions that involve title insurance don't have that risk, which is one of the reasons it is required when obtaining a mortgage.  You can also purchase a foreclosure or otherwise distressed property and get title insurance, but not typically at auction.

It should be noted that there is probably interest that needs to be considered also, those fees are almost 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

That obligation "runs with the land". You'll have to pay it.